# How can I get sorting, paging and filtering on a Repository without MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create just the back-end part for a simple CRUD project. I'm completely new to asp.net and currently reading as I go. But I got stuck.

I've created the entities (models) I need

```
public class VehicleMakeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Abrv { get; set; }

    public VehicleMakeEntity Make { get; set; }
}
```

I've also created a standard DbContext class and the repositories

```
class MakeRepository : IMakeRepository
{
    ProjectDbContext context;

    public MakeRepository(ProjectDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void Delete(VehicleMakeEntity entity)
    {
        context.VehicleMake.Remove(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
        Console.WriteLine(entity.Make.Name);
    }

    public void Insert(VehicleMakeEntity entity)
    {
        context.VehicleMake.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update(VehicleMakeEntity entity)
    {
        context.VehicleMake.Update(entity);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now the problem I have is I cannot find any documentation that both doesn't use MVC and uses repositories. 
I need to create a service class that implements basic paging, sorting and filtering but everything I look at [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083703/sorting-and-paging-on-repository) uses MVC and I have no idea how to convert it to my project.

Comment: If you are just starting out, I would suggest you 2 things: first of all, ditch completely anything you read related to Unit of Work / Repository, there are too few cases where those are required and be sure you don't need it if you are just learning. Secondly, ditch ASP.NET  and EF and learn ASP.NET Core and EF Core

Comment: Another notice: the Q&A you linked is terribly wrong in two important aspects: first it fails at Dependency Injection, and secondly and most important, it loads an entire table to memory to then use a couple of values in the paginator.

Comment: I'm following a few tasks, they require the use of repositories. And yeah my bad about not making it clear, I am using ASP.NET Core and EF Core. After I'm done with the basics of the tasks I will most likely switch over to Razor pages as I read that everyone should learn that.

Comment: you should update your tags to mentioning "core" also your title and body

Comment: Razor Pages is for extremely simple web pages (think almost static information) or javascript intensive applications that don't use server-side MVC at all. If you plan on working on most real-world applications, you'll need MVC.

Comment: I am not sure if you are getting what MVC is. Why exactly are you trying to avoid MVC? are you trying to make a website directly with repositories?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane They are most likely following some course/online tutorial

Comment: I'm not trying to avoid MVC. Like @CamiloTerevinto said. I am following tasks to be done and trying to learn based on that. After I create the paging, sorting, filtering and use automapper to map the objects, I will be required to start using MVC and basically rewrite half the things.

Comment: I strongly recommend you go the other way around. I know there are many ways these are documented, but in any way i see this, it makes sense to understand the basics of MVC first, even before you learn about EF. What the code you have shown, if you want to impliment paging etc before MVC, the best I can recommend is concole based application. which is a lot more work

Comment: are you ok with completly keeping websites aside untill you test out paging, sorting, filtering, etc?

Comment: I understand, and I know the concept of MVC. I have never written anything in ASP.NET Core, though I am not that new to programming. Just wanted to learn basic c# web development. The main goal currently is to create and test out paging, sorting and filtering. So if I understood your question correctly, yes.

Comment: Basically, I can show you a way where you can test these concepts out in raw command line. Just to clarify my question, are you find with testing them out in a purely console based app with console inputs and outputs?

Comment: Any type of help/example would be great. Though, and this may sound really stupid. I am currently not using any sort of testing nor did I know you could. I literally just created a class library, wrote code and test if it builds (no errors).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on your code and comments, you have a setup that is meant for .NET Core web apps that can be implemented with services (dependency injection). You can, however, run the entire dependency injection setup on a console based app that doesn't host a web app.

First, you will need to add the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package so you get all the classes you might be using (mainly `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`).
You can now build your service provider something like this:

```
var provider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddDbContext<ProjectDbContext>(config => // connection here)
                .AddScoped<IMakeRepository, MakeRepository>()
                .BuildServiceProvider();
```

You can now fetch any service you want out of your provider. The above code also allows you to add any service you find in any .NET Core MVC tutorial since it uses the same classes and libraries. Let's say you want to fetch the `IMakeRepository`, you can use the following:

```
var makeRepo = provider.GetService<IMakeRepository>();
```

You can now test out the functions inside your `makeRepo` object.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore,All` is an insanely huge meta-package. You only need to install `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`

Comment: The downvote doesn't make any sense. First of all, it resolves the issue. Secondly running locally and for a test, I don't see how several packages could be a big issue. Thirdly, NO you don't need only the DI package. The `AddDbContext` function is inside `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` nuget. That is just one example. Based on what I explained he can do with this code, he needs to keep installing packages for each need. Explaining the need of `Microsoft.AspNetCore,All` further just go back to the purpose of the package in the first place.